# sending JSON with multipartentitybuilder

Tags: java, android, json, apache, multipartentity

I am trying to send json with files using **multipartentitybuilder**
I am receiving `{"access_token"=>"1234", "title"=>"davac", "description"=>"vasdv", "subject"=>"{\"id\":\"100\"}"}`
at server side. "{\"id\":\"100\"} is a json string and I am trying to send it using

```
mMultipartEntityBuilder.addTextBody(name, new StringBody(text, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

I dont want **\"** at server side..

Comment: And what did you sent?

Comment: @ greenapps text was a json string. I convert it using JacksonJSONParser's toJson method.

Comment: Well I asked how that string looked. What you sent. You showed what you received already.

Comment: @greenapps {"id":"100"}

Comment: Well somebody has escaped it. So then you have to unescape it. Or blame the receiver.